# PHP MySQLi Pagination

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to build a pagination app however my code keeps failing and I don't know why. It works when I replace the LIMIT variables with numbers but not with variables in the query.

```
$pageNum = $_GET['page'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];
if ($pageNum == NULL) {
$pageNum = 1;   
}
include("config.php");
include("header.php");

$numPosts = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE category='" . $id . "'         ORDER BY latestReply ASC");
$numPosts = $numPost->num_rows;
$resultsPerPage = 10;
$lastPage = ceil($numPosts/$resultsPerPage);

if (!(isset($pagenum))){ 
 $pageNum = 1; 
 }

 if ($pagenum < 1) { 
 $pageNum = 1; 
 } elseif ($pageNum > $lastPage) { 
 $pageNum = $lastPage; 
 } 

$limit1 = $pageNum * $resultsPerPage - $resultsPerPage;
$limit2 = $limit1 + $resultsPerPage;
$post = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM forum_posts LIMIT $limt1, $limit2 WHERE category='" . $id . "' ORDER BY latestReply ASC");
```

I keep getting this error however:

```
[17-Nov-2013 17:12:22 Europe/London] PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/robbiewi/public_html/forum/category.php on line 59
```

On this line:

```
while ($posts = mysqli_fetch_array($post)) {
```

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection. Why don’t you [use prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE` condition should be placed before the `LIMIT`

should be

`SELECT * FROM forum_posts  WHERE category='" . $id . "' ORDER BY latestReply ASC  LIMIT $limt1, $limit2`

instead of,

`SELECT * FROM forum_posts LIMIT $limt1, $limit2 WHERE category='" . $id . "' ORDER BY latestReply ASC`

Select syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

```
SELECT
[ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
  [HIGH_PRIORITY]
  [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
  [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
  [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
select_expr [, select_expr ...]
[FROM table_references
[WHERE where_condition]
[GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
  [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
[HAVING where_condition]
[ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
  [ASC | DESC], ...]
[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
[PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
[INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' export_options
  | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
  | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
[FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]
```

Comment: Thanks I had never seen that Select Syntax before!

Answer (score 0):

1. You wrote $limt1 in your SQL statement, but I guess you just misstyped it right now.
2. Are you sure that $limit1 and $limit2 are numbers? Maybe you could fix it when you use `$limit1 = $limit1 * 1` to be sure it's number, worked for me sometimes.

Comment: Yeah I fixed the typo just after i posted here. Thanks